# Rails - 3 column association table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model

I am currently trying to create a fairly simple association in Rails, but it is proving more difficult than I thought.

I have 3 models, User, Dealer and Role. User/dealer is many to many. Users can have many roles, but they should be specific to a dealership - i.e. a user can have the roles manager and director at one dealership, manager only at another, and be chairman in another.

The outcome I am looking for is that I will be able to do `user.dealer.roles` and (e.g. for the first dealer) it would return manager and director. The same would happen if I did `dealer.user.roles.`

My classes look as follows:

```
class User  :dealer_users
  has_many :dealer_user_roles, :through => :dealer_users
  has_many :roles, :through => :dealer_user_roles
end

class Dealer  :dealer_users
  has_many :dealer_user_roles, :through => :dealer_users
  has_many :roles, :through => :dealer_user_roles
end

class Role  :dealer_user_roles
  has_many :users, :through => :dealer_users
end
```

The tables look like (green tables):

[image: Model diagram]

I am trying to seed the database using the following code:

```
dealer = Dealer.where(name: Faker::Company.name).first_or_create
user = User.where(email: Faker::Internet.email).first_or_create
user.first_name = Faker::Name.first_name 
user.last_name = Faker::Name.last_name
user.password = 'password'
user.password_confirmation = 'password'
dealer.users  user.id).first.roles  1 + Random.rand(4))
```

This results in an error, which is: "Cannot modify association 'User#roles' because it goes through more than one other association."

Can anyone assist by telling me where I am going wrong, and how I can put it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I would model it as:

```
# Table name: users
#  id          :integer  not null, primary key
#  name        :string
class User
  has_many :employments
  has_many :dealers, :through => :employments
  has_many :roles, :through => :employments
end

# Table name: dealers
#  id          :integer  not null, primary key
#  name        :string
class Dealer
  has_many :employments
  has_many :users, :through => :employments
  has_many :roles, :through => :employments
end

# Table name: employments
#  id          :integer  not null, primary key
#  user_id     :integer  not null
#  dealer_id   :integer  not null
class Employment
 belongs_to :dealer, :inverse_of => :employments
 belongs_to :user,   :inverse_of => :employments
 has_many :roles
 scope :for_user,   lambda{ |user| where(:user_id => user.id) }
 scope :for_dealer, lambda{ |dealer| where(:dealer_id => dealer.id) }
end

# Table name: roles
#  id             :integer   not null, primary key
#  employment_id  :integer   not null
#  name           :string    not null
class Role
  belongs_to :employment
  scope :at_dealership, lambda{ |dealer| joins(:employment).where(:dealer_id => dealer.id) }
  scope :for_employee,  lambda{ |employee| joins(:employment).where(:user_id => employee.id) }
  # alternately:
  # scope :at_dealership, lambda{ |dealer| joins(:employment).where('employments.dealer_id = ?', dealer.id) }
  # scope :for_employee,  lambda{ |employee| joins(:employment).where('employments.user_id = ?',employee.id) }
end
```

This makes it easier to deal with, and also puts the roles where they actually belong - on the combination of user/dealer which I've called employment.

you can then say

```
dealer.users.first.roles 
# or
user.dealers.where('some condition').roles
```

EDIT: with scopes all of these should do what you want.

```
user = User.first
dealer = user.dealers.first

user.roles.at_dealership(dealer)

dealer.roles.for_employee(user)

dealer.employments.for_user(user).roles

user.employments.for_dealer(dealer).roles
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks for your answer, I modelled the relationship in this way and it appeared to work. Having just tested, however, I am finding that dealer.user.first.roles brings up all roles at all dealerships associated with that user, not just the roles associated with the selected dealer - is this expected?

Comment: The syntax you want could never work to get you what you want using ActiveRecord. user.dealer will give you a dealer,  and unless you scope somehow (like I just did with named scopes) dealer.roles is going to get all the roles for that dealer. I've edited the example to show you a Railsy way of getting the data that you want. Other ways of getting your syntax are going to conflict with ActiveRecord and be very hard to implement. I've not tested this, so you may have to adjust the contents of the where() methods to include table names.